# Selecting an item with a certain grandchild.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this part in my html file

```
<ul class="noBullets horizontalList">
    <li> <a href="home.html">Home</a> </li>     

    <li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li> 

    <li> 
        <form>
            <input type="search" name="search" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
        </form> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

And I need in the js file to select any item in a horizontal-list  that contains a submit button and make it float to the right. I tried this and did not work:

```
$('li:contains(type="submit")').css("float", "right");
```

Is there any clean way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('li').filter(function( index ) {
    return $('form button[type="submit"]', this).length > 0;
}).css("float", "right");;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with `'li:contains(type="submit")'`:

1. The [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) syntax requires square brackets, like `'[type="submit"]'`, but...
2. The [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selects elements that contain the specified *text*, not a nested selector.

I would probably approach this from the inside out, that is, select the button(s) first, then navigate up to the containing li element(s) using the [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').closest('li').css("float", "right");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="noBullets horizontalList">
    <li> <a href="home.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li> 
    <li> 
        <form>
            <input type="search" name="search" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
        </form> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```